# Does POST hide passwords?

Tags: php, html

I made a login form that uses POST. The thing is I go in Chrome->Inspect element->Network->Headers->Form data and it shows the info that was entered in the form, which includes the password in plaintext. I did look upon other websites in the same manner and it shows it there, too. My question is, how secure is this thing? Basicly, anyone can see the passwords?

Comment: Yes. Anyone can see the HTTP requests (including POST data/files/GET/headers/cookies) coming back and forth on a network line, unless you use HTTPS.

Comment: Is there any reason to not use HTTPS? Why doesn't everyone use it, every website?

Comment: No, at best you can consider it "hidden" in that POST passes the data via the request body instead of the url. `example.com/login.php?user=foo&password=bar` would show up in the server's access log, but on a post, all you'd get is `example.com/login.php`.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc You have to use a valid certificate or you get a big nasty error. These valid certificates can be cheap, but they can also be very expensive (for those that work in nearly every browser, even super old ones). Apparently [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) give out free personal certificates.

Comment: Is the data stored upon closing the web page or moving on? Or is it deleted?

Comment: Once you've made the HTTP request the data has been sent and will not be resent, unless you, the user, decide to.

Comment: It depends on the developer and what they think they need to do with a password.

Comment: No, what I mean. Is that information(the HTTP request info) stored somewhere? Or the only way to see the form data is to go to inspect element...etc.?

Comment: The only way for others to see your password is a [Man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).